# "An error has occurred. Try again later." in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Has anyone experienced this issue? Every time I attempt to add a new build to the internal tester in App Store Connect, it displays an error message:

> "An error has occurred. Try again later."

[image]

I attempted to resolve the issue by relogging into the account, clearing the history, creating a new archive, and then trying to add it to the internal tester. However, the problem persisted.

Comment: I think that builds are automatically distributed to internal testers (App Store Connect user). Only Xcode Cloud-Builds must be added manually.

Comment: @Yedy This problem didn't exist until about a week ago. I used to add builds from here to internal testers without any issues. However, I have recently encountered this problem where adding a build from here is no longer possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. If you're encountering this issue, there's another method to add a new build to the internal testers. Here's how:

1. Generate a new build using Xcode and upload it to TestFlight.
2. Once the upload is complete, navigate to the TestFlight section in App Store Connect.
3. On the left-hand side, you'll find an option called "iOS Builds." Click on it.
4. After the processing is finished, you will be able to locate the recently submitted build. Click on it.
5. Below, there will be an option to "Add Group." Select this option.
6. Choose the groups you've set up for internal testers from the list.
7. After selecting the groups, save your changes. The build will now be automatically added to the internal group.
8. Finally, select the internal testers, and you should see your latest build included there

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a new internal test group (Plus-Button next to Internal Test) and check "Enable automatic distribution". All new/latest iOS Builds will be available to internal testers instantly.
[image: (]

Comment: You are correct, but that's not what I'm looking for. I was asking to resolve that issue without creating a new internal group. I wanted to address the problem with the existing internal group, which I have already resolved and mentioned above. Thanks for your response.